# In a watchOS how to create a link to settings - general - wake screen

Tags: swift, deep-linking, url-scheme, watchos

In a watchOS how to create a link, URL schema or deep-link to settings - general  - wake screen?

in my watchOS app, I run a test to find out if the wake screen is set to 15 seconds or 70 seconds. If the test fails when the app becomes inactive after 15 seconds i want to redirect the user to the wake screen settings in the setting app so they can change the setting to 70 seconds.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In general you should be able to just setup background modes and establish a WKExtendedRuntimeSession to facilitate whatever you're trying to accomplish.